# Trigger native Google play game service login from webview

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I would like to know if it is possible to trigger the native Google Play Game Services login window from javascript (inside a webview).

Here you have an example of the login window I am referring to:
[image: Screenshot]

Is it possible? I am starting to think that it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an Javascript Interface

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Set it to the WebView

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

And finally call it from Javascript

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

There is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I think I haven't explained myself correctly. I know that I can access Android system from Javascript using an interface as you explained (thanks for that!) what I really want is the particular screen that I showed in the example, the one that logs you in Google Play Game Services. And doing it from javascript directly inside a webview.